# Align inline text input in Bootstrap Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form in Bootstrap and need the `first name` and `last name` fields to be inline where as the rest of the form needs to be as it is.

I got the inline functionality to work. However, the inline text fields (names) are not aligning properly.

[image: Form Image]

In the image above, I need the combined width of the name fields to be same as Phone, Email and Password fields, which is not happening. The question is **how to get that alignment to work**?

The code for the form is below:

```
<form role="form" class="register-form cf-style-1">

<div class="control-group" style="display:inline-block !important; margin-bottom: 25px;">
    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="le-input" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" style="display:inline-block !important; margin-bottom: 25px;">
    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="le-input" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field-row">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">+91</div>
        <input type="text" class="le-input" maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone Number">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field-row">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="le-input" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div><!-- /.field-row -->

<div class="field-row">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="le-input" placeholder="Password" required>
</div><!-- /.field-row -->

<div class="buttons-holder">
    <button type="submit" class="le-button huge">Sign Up</button>
</div><!-- /.buttons-holder -->
</form>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the style of the inline-block. Then just add the class col-md-6 to each of the divs you want to be side by side. This will cause them to be a two column layout for medium displays then they will be on their own line on smaller displays. You can read more about columns here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what css you have to go along with this, might be useful if we can see a link to this.

But you could try adding `width: 50%` to the First and Last name input tags.

```
input {width: 50%;}
```

I would target these inputs by adding classes to the ones you want to change, as not to affect the other input tags

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls form-inline">
            <label for="inputKey">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="le-input" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <label for="inputValue">LastName</label>
             <input type="text" class="le-input" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```